# Circular connections in flow chart between blocks

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

how can i connect two blocks with a circular arrow? 
Please see below the example that i've managed to create so far:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 3cm, auto]

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=white!20, 
text width=5.5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em]
\tikzstyle{line} = [draw, -latex']


\node [block] (1) {Text 1};
\node [block, below right of=1] (2) {Text 2};
\node [block, below left of=2] (3) {Text 3};
\node [block, above left of=3] (4) {Text 4};

\path [line] (1) -- (2);
\path [line] (2) -- (3);
\path [line] (3) -- (4);
\path [line] (4) -- (1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is the current result:
[image]

This is a quick sketch of the result i would like to have:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could play with `to[out=..., in=...]`, where `out` and `in` are respectively the angle of exit and entry to the node. You could also choose the anchor position, for example `(2.60)` means node named `2` at `60` degrees, `0` is east.

By the way:

1. [Should \tikzset or \tikzstyle be used to define TikZ styles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/52372/should-tikzset-or-tikzstyle-be-used-to-define-tikz-styles)
2. [Difference between "right of=" and "right=of" in PGF/TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9386/difference-between-right-of-and-right-of-in-pgf-tikz)
3. moreover, `tikzset` sets the style for all your `tikzpicture`s, if you want to set them only for the current picture, just put them directly as `tikzpicture` environment options.

Here my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, positioning}

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{empty}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance=4ex and 0em,
        block/.style={rectangle, draw, fill=white!20, 
    text width=5.5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=4em},
        line/.style={draw, -latex},
        ]

        \node [block] (1) {Text 1};
        \node [block, below right= of 1] (2) {Text 2};
        \node [block, below left= of 2] (3) {Text 3};
        \node [block, above left= of 3] (4) {Text 4};

        \path [line] (1.east) to[out=0, in=90] (2.60);
        \path [line] (2.-60) to[out=-90, in=0] (3.east);
        \path [line] (3.west) to[out=180, in=-90] (4.-120);
        \path [line] (4.120) to[out=90, in=180] (1.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly the result i was looking for.  Also thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 3):

You can use for example the "bend"-option with
    \path [line] (4) to[bend left=65] (1);

In your code it will be

```
\path [line] (1) to[bend left=45] (2);
\path [line] (2) to[bend left=45] (3);
\path [line] (3) to[bend left=45] (4);
\path [line] (4) to[bend left=45] (1);
```

By changing the value you can change the angles of the line.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit automated but sure not perfect:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,calc}

\newcommand{\circular}[2]{
\node (0) at (0,0){};
\xdef\Radious{#2}
\foreach \nodetext[count=\i] in {#1} {
\xdef\totalIt{\i}
}
\foreach \nodetext[count=\i] in {#1} {
\pgfmathsetmacro\myprev{int{\i-1}}
\pgfmathsetmacro\curxdispl{cos(90-360/\totalIt*(\i-1))*\Radious}
\pgfmathsetmacro\curydispl{sin(90-360/\totalIt*(\i-1))*\Radious}
\path  ($(\curxdispl cm,\curydispl cm)$) node[block,anchor=center] (\i) {\nodetext};
}

\foreach \nodetext[count=\i] in {#1}{
\pgfmathsetmacro\mynext{\ifnum\i<\totalIt int(\i+1)\else 1\fi}
\path[draw,-latex] (\i) to[bend left] (\mynext);
}
}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}




\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=white!20, 
text width=2.5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=3em]
\circular{test1,test2,test3}{2}
\end{tikzpicture}\vspace{40pt}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, draw, fill=white!20, 
text width=3.5em, text centered, rounded corners, minimum height=2em]
\circular{test1,test2,test3,test4,test5}{4}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]