# How to change the color and arrow of the circular diagram of the smartdiagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

https://texdoc.org/serve/smartdiagram/0

page 4 has a basic circular diagram.

```
\begin{center}
\smartdiagram[circular diagram]{Set up,Run,Analyse,Modify~/ Add}
\end{center}
```

I want to set

*each box shape rectangle without any shades

*each box has no filling color (transparent)

*arrow color black and a direct edge

Please advise.

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. Please, can you formulate well your question to be more clear putting also the complete code in .tex starting from \documentclass to \end{document} and not a link?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398680/circular-connections-in-flow-chart-between-blocks

Comment: Is this the output you're interested in? https://i.stack.imgur.com/vCx2z.png If so, it is probably easier to achieve using tikz directly instead of through the smartdiagram package.